# Application crash due to INVALID PARAMETER after call in std::condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, condition-variable

I have an application that spawns some 20 threads using `_beginthreadex`. All of the threads are waiting on a queue to be filled which is a wrapper over the `std::queue` : `class MyQueue`.The `queue` is created as a global variable something like `MyQueue processQueue`

The `front` function of `MyQueue` looks something like,

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        while (queue_.empty())
        {
            cond_.wait(mlock);
        }
        auto item = queue_.front();
        queue_.pop();
        return item;
```

And push looks like:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        queue_.push(item);
        mlock.unlock();
        cond_.notify_one();
```

`cond_,queue_ and mutex_` are member variable of `MyQueue`.
So initially, all the threads are in waiting state. When the `queue` has an item, one of the thread reads it and process it.
The problem occurs when the application is closed, gracefully or abruptly. There is a crash in the `msvcr120!Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::notify_all`.

Entire stack from the crash dump

```
ntdll!TppRaiseInvalidParameter+0x48
ntdll!TpAllocWait+0x6725f
kernel32!CreateThreadpoolWaitStub+0x1a
msvcr120!Concurrency::details::ExternalContextBase::PrepareForUse+0xa1
msvcr120!Concurrency::details::ExternalContextBase::ExternalContextBase+0xa2
msvcr120!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::AttachExternalContext+0xcf
Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::CreateContextFromDefaultScheduler+0xfe
msvcr120!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::CurrentContext+0x26
msvcr120!Concurrency::critical_section::scoped_lock::scoped_lock+0x47
msvcr120!Concurrency::details::_Condition_variable::notify_all+0x23
msvcp120!_Cnd_destroy+0x1b
myfunction+0x36c501
msvcr120!doexit+0x145
msvcr120!__CRTDLL_INIT+0xce
ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x41
ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess+0x142
ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x78
KERNELBASE!DefaultHandler+0xf
KERNELBASE!CtrlRoutine+0x9b
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d`
```

Things i tried,

1. use `std::unique_ptr` for the condition variable but it didn't fix the issue.
2. call _endthreadex(0) in the `dtor` of the queue. This fixed the crash on exit, but i dont think this is the correct way as i am not sure which of thread is getting closed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As a general rule, unless you *reall* know what is going on regarding pending destructions (and currently active destructions), avoid using _endthread and _endthreadex in MS C++ programs. It sounds like your queue is being destroyed (and thus all those members) while there are still outstanding threads waiting on them. You need to stop that by lining up an alternate exit strat for the threads, signal them to pick up that state, then join them as they *graceully* shut down so the cvar, mtx, and queue are no long in concurrency.

Comment: This is a program shutdown problem, it bombs because the threadpool no longer exists.  Cleanly terminating a program with umpteen threads can be quite difficult, you may have to resort to std::quick_exit().  But proper advice can't be given without repro code.  The exact same scenario is described in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120427-00/?p=7763).

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem. Did you find any solutions for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

this is crt bug. crash because `std::condition_variable` destructor called from `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

> `MyQueue queue` is created as a global variable and `cond_`, are
>   member variable of `MyQueue`

because `cond_` is global object in DLL - it destructor called on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`

from stack trace clear visible that all begin from `_Cnd_destroy` (called from destructor of conditional variable). crt internally call [`CreateThreadpoolWait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682474(v=vs.85).aspx). which call `TpAllocWait`. at very begin of this api exist next line of code:

```
if (RtlGetCurrentPeb()->Ldr->ShutdownInProgress) TppRaiseInvalidParameter();
```

because [`CreateThreadpoolWait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682474(v=vs.85).aspx) called after `ExitProcess` called (look in stack trace `ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess`) (in `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` handler) - the  `ShutdownInProgress` already `true` and as result `TppRaiseInvalidParameter` called - again clear visible from your stack trace.

here - [std::condition_variable destructor crashes on VS2012](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5d269ca-0b8d-40ed-bcf5-fec622a854d9/stdconditionvariable-destructor-crashes-on-vs2012) another example of this crash. - if you look to stack trace of the crash - you can view that it absolute the same (highlight main points in stack)

```
ntdll.dll!_NtRaiseException@12
  ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8
  ntdll.dll!_TpAllocWait@16
  kernel32.dll!_CreateThreadpoolWait@12
  msvcp110d.dll!_Cnd_destroy(_Cnd_internal_imp_t * * cond) Line 35 C++
  ConnectModelUtil.dll!std::condition_variable::~condition_variable() Line 41 C++
  ConnectModelUtil.dll!_CRT_INIT(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved) Line 416 C
  ConnectModelUtil.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved) Line 522 C
```

so only solution here - not use global `condition_variable` object in dll - otherwise you got crash on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`

---

also from [std::condition_variable::~condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/%7Econdition_variable)

> The programmer must ensure that no threads attempt to wait on *this
>   once the destructor has been started

but this is not true in your case. your threads terminated during wait on conditional variable `cond_.wait(mlock);`. so from conditional variable view - threads still waiting - it data (pointers to it blocks allocated from it stack) linked to conditional variable. you need or somehow unwait all threads before `ExitProcess` call - but you can not do this from `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` which is called after this - for this exe must call some dll function before. or not use wait on dll global conditional variable

Comment: the `cond_`is not a global variable. It is member of `MyQueue` object. The object however is global.

Comment: @KartikkumarRao - what you say that is mean that cond_is a global variable. it separate or part of another global object not play any role. the destructor in both case called on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wake up the wait for shutdown. `cond_.notify_all()` in destructor of your class fix your problem?

Comment: but `notify_all()` and called from destructor and exactly this call produce crash.

Comment: No `notify_all()`doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: and you acquired the according mutex too?

Answer (score 0):

Compiled code using vc140 using visual studio 2015 and there was no more crash. Looks like visual studio 2013 bug after all.