# nofify_all() crashes when the program is closed

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I have a very simple C++ program like below. The A, B and C classes are inside a DLL. When I close this application, it sometimes crashing while calling notify_all() on the condition variable. Can anybody give me a hint about the reason?

I have checked lots of Q/As on SO, but none of them solved my problem. I work on windows 7 and VS2013.

```
    class B;

    class C
    {
    public:
        C(const std::weak_ptr<B>& b) : mB(b)
        {
        }
        virtual ~C() 
        {
        }

        void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uLock(mMutex);

                // Wait until some event is happening
                mCondition.wait_for(uLock, std::chrono::seconds(300));

                if (!mStop)
                {
                    //do something here
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }


        void start()
        {
            mThread = std::thread(&C::run, this);
        }

        void stop()
        {
            mStop = false;
        }

        void notify()
        {
            mCondition.notify_all();
        }

        void join()
        {
            if (mThread.joinable())
            {
                mThread.join();
            }
        }

        private:
            std::atomic<bool> mStop;
            std::condition_variable mCondition;
            std::mutex mMutex;
            std::thread mThread;
            std::weak_ptr<B> mB;
        };


    class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B>
    {
    public:
        B() {}
        ~B()
        {
            if (mC)
            {
                mC->stop();
                mC->notify();
                mC->join();
            }
        }

        // basic methods
        void init()
        {
            mC = std::unique_ptr<C>(new C(shared_from_this()));
            mC->start();
        }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<C> mC;
    };

    class A
    {
    public:
        ~A(){}

        void init() { pImpl->init(); }

        static std::shared_ptr<A> getInstance(){
            static std::shared_ptr<A> instance(new A);
            return instance;
        }

    private:
        A() : pImpl(std::make_shared<B>()){}
        std::shared_ptr<B> pImpl;
    };


    void main()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> a = A::getInstance();
        a->init();

        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
    }
```

**Edit 1:** If I put the code in B's destructor in a different function (e.g. clean()) and call it from main() (using a clean() method in A) no crash is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a CRT bug (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50525968/896012). The problem does not happen on new versions of Windows, i.e. Windows 10. To fix the crash on Windows 7, I just removed the condition_variable and used a simple sleep instead and while exiting the program I just detached the thread. Although this is not a clean approach, but I think it is the only way to avoid the crash. If anyone found a better answer, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The code misses the condition variable notification because:

1. The mutex is not held during `stop_ = true` (it should be `true`, not `false`). `stop_` must be read and modified while the mutex is held and it doesn't need to be atomic. This is a common cause of race conditions when people use atomics along with mutexes and condition variables.
2. The condition variable waiting code doesn't check the condition before waiting.

Fixes:

```
class B;

class C
{
public:
    C(const std::weak_ptr<B>& b) : mB(b) {}
    ~C() { stop(); }

    void run()
    {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uLock(mMutex);
            while(!mStop /* && !other_real_condition */)
                mCondition.wait_for(uLock, std::chrono::seconds(300));
            if(mStop)
                return;
            // other_real_condition is true, process it.
        }
    }


    void start()
    {
        mThread = std::thread(&C::run, this);
    }

    void stop()
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uLock(mMutex);
            mStop = true;
        }
        mCondition.notify_all();
        if (mThread.joinable())
            mThread.join();
    }

    private:
        bool mStop = false; // <--- do not forget to initialize
        std::condition_variable mCondition;
        std::mutex mMutex;
        std::thread mThread;
        std::weak_ptr<B> mB;
    };


class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
public:

    // basic methods
    void init()
    {
        mC = std::unique_ptr<C>(new C(shared_from_this()));
        mC->start();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<C> mC;
};
```

If you set `mStop` without holding the mutex the following happens:

```
| Thread 1              | Thread 2            |
| mStop = true          |                     |
| mCondition.notify_all |                     |
|                       | mMutex.lock         |
|                       | mCondition.wait_for |
```

In the above Thread 2 loses the notification and waits although `mStop` was set.

Locking the mutex when updating the shared state fixes that race condition:

```
| Thread 1                | Thread 2               |
| mMutex.lock             |                        |
| mStop = true            |                        |
| mCondition.notify_all   |                        |
| mMutex.unlock           |                        |
|                         | mMutex.lock            |
|                         | mStop == true, no wait |
```

When waiting on condition variables the shared state must be modified and read while the mutex lock is held, otherwise condition notifications get lost and that may result in a deadlock (when waiting with no timeout). This is why using atomics along with mutexes and condition variables is unnecessary, you either use atomics or mutexes and condition variables but not both.

Comment: why I should put the wait_for function on a while loop? Actually, in my case, I do not have a real_condition. I just want to do some code every 300 seconds and if another thread wants to stop, i want to stop this thread as well.

Comment: @hsalimi There are condition variable spurious wakeups. Condition variables do not have state so that notifications can be lost. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup

Comment: But in my case, if I use the wait_for(...) in a while loop, after 5 minutes, the thread will wake up and go to sleep again. No? I cannot have a real_condition instead of the time out.

Comment: @hsalimi Added details for you.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. It is now clear for me. The last Q is that in your sample code, you release mMutex just after setting mStop to true, but in your thread swimlanes depicted after, you release this mutex after calling notify_all. Which one should be the correct answer? Is it necessary to hold the lock while calling notify_all?

Comment: @hsalimi Signaling after releasing the mutex is an optimization. If you signal while holding the mutex the other thread waiting on the condition variable is woken up only to be blocked on re-acquiring the mutex.

Comment: The program still is crashing. It seems to be a VS bug (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50525968/896012).

Comment: @hsalimi I do not have access to VS, unfortunately.